# Cannot convert type `UnityEngine.GameObject' to `UnityEngine.Rigidbody'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've some Error!

**Unity 3D**

```
    Rigidbody bullet = (Rigidbody)Instantiate(projectile, transform.position + transform.forward, transform.rotation);
    bullet.AddForce(transform.forward * bulletImpulse, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

But I've error in this code

> Cannot convert type `UnityEngine.GameObject' to`UnityEngine.Rigidbody'

thank for your help 
Please Help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Instantiate` method returns a `GameObject`, not a `Rigidbody`. `Rigidbody` is a *component* of that game object, so to get it, you have to call `GetComponent`:

```
GameObject gameObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(projectile, transform.position + transform.forward, transform.rotation);
Rigidbody bullet = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need get component to use :

```
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html
```

Final code:

```
Rigidbody bullet = ((GameObject)Instantiate(projectile, transform.position + transform.forward, transform.rotation)).GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
bullet.AddForce(transform.forward * bulletImpulse, ForceMode.Impulse);
```